# I need to get the int value in a variable which was selected statement from stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and values like this

```
create table exTABLE(abc int)

insert into exTABLE(abc) values(10)
insert into exTABLE(abc) values(20)
insert into exTABLE(abc) values(30)
```

I have created a stored procedure like this

```
alter procedure proced
    @tablename varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @sql as varchar(max)
    set @sql='select max(abc) from '+@tablename

    --print @sql
    exec(@sql)
end
```

I will get the result as 30 and that is correct answer, but I need to put the resultant selected 30 into a separate int variable inside the stored procedure and I need to get it as output, i.e I tried to do like this

```
alter procedure proced
    @tablename varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @sql as varchar(max)

    set @sql = 'select max(abc) from '+@tablename

    --print @sql
    exec(@sql)

    declare @i as int
    set @i = cast(@sql as int)

    exec(@i)
    print @i
end
```

I need to get the printed value of i as 30 . ANY ALTERNATE METHOD ALSO WILL BE VERY USEFUL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare @sql as nvarchar and use sp_executesql instead. Pass input and output parameter to collect the result from the sql statement in a int variable.

```
 Alter procedure proced
 @tablename varchar(max)
 as
 begin

declare @sql as nvarchar(max),@i int
, @Param nvarchar(500);
set @sql='select @i1=max(abc) from '+@tablename
SET @Param = N'@i1 int OUTPUT';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @Param, @i1=@i OUTPUT;

Print @i
Select @i


end

exec proced 'exTABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will both print and return:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE proced
 @tablename VARCHAR(max)
 AS
 BEGIN

  DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(max)

  SET @sql='DECLARE @i AS INT; SELECT @i = MAX(abc) FROM '+@tablename + ';PRINT @i; SELECT @i'

  exec(@sql)

END
```

Comment: i need to get the print @i outside of exec(@sql)

Comment: @navs - not sure I understand why. it prints :)